# Prefixing All Rails Routes with a Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, path, routes, directory

I have a Rails 3.2 application with numerous resources. **How can I change the routing so that every path has an extra directory prepended it?** Obvioulsy I know how to do this on a resource by resource basis, but how do I do it to all routes?

So for example:

- users
- users/1
- resources/new
- resources/77/edit
- assets/66

Would become:

- cms/users
- cms/users/1
- cms/resources/new
- cms/resources/77/edit
- cms/assets/66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing). Basically, you need:

```
namespace :cms do
  #all your resources
end
```